# How do I get CAML for a custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the CAML for a custom content type that I am creating. What I am really doing is creating the content type in Visual Studio 2010 via CAML and then deploying that content type to my sandbox using the new deploy features in VS 2010. At that point, I am modifying the content type using the SharePoint interface (i.e changing advanced settings, adding columns, etc) since it is easy to do via the web interface. What I would like to do, is after I have made my changed, update my CAML in Visual Studio to match my changes.

I want to do this because I am creating custom fields and content types for my project and want to create a solution with these customizations. Since there doesn't seem to be a way to do this (create custom fields and content types) as a solution using SharePoint without putting them into a list, I am using Visual Studio and CAML for this. I also want to use Visual Studio and CAML so that I can put these CAML xml files in source control so that I can version my custom fields and custom types.

I have tried using tools like http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/ but that doesn't seem to work with SP 2010.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I wish Visual Studio would just have an update from SP button after I have deployed my solution and made changes on the server so it would sync VS from the SP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/Wikipage)

Comment: This does what I want although its not ideal as that would be a Visual Studio command to update the content type or field schema Xml but this will work.. thanks!